# Topshelf NLog Ensure Flush

Tags: c#, nlog, topshelf

I have seen code examples that look like this to ensure that if your application crashes, your logs get written. I understand this and the variations of the code shown below.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // NLog: setup the logger first to catch all errors
        var logger = LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init main");
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

However, Topshelf [recommends](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/logging.html) implementing logging with NLog like this:

```
HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.UseNLog();
});
```

Does the code:

> x.UseNLog();

ensure that logs are written when the service fails/crashes ungracefully? i.e. does it implement behind the scenes:

```
// Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
```

Alternatively, where should I implement this code?

Comment: Yes it would be nice if TopShelf had the ability to dispose its LogWriter on shutdown. Then the specific LogWriter-implementation could implement its individual flush / close / shutdown-logic. Sounds like an issue/feature-request for the TopShelf GitHub-repository.

Comment: But right now you should keep `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();` in the bottom of the try/catch/finally in the `Main`-method (Along with error-logging on unhandled exception).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see [here](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/commit/0961fa4b11650a0506878c50c89389dfa32fadc1) in Github, `UseNLog` will cause a call to `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()`:

```
    public class NLogLogWriterFactory :
        LogWriterFactory
    {
...
        public void Shutdown()
        {
            _logFactory.Flush();
            _logFactory.SuspendLogging();
            
            LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
...
    }
```

(`LogWriterFactory` is an interface here, and `Shutdown` is an implementation of the corresponding method of this interface).

According to tags, the commit should be present in all versions of Topshelf NuGet package starting from `4.3.0`. So no need to call `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` manually.